# Regex to match directory followed by dot

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a JavaScript regex that can match a directory followed by a dot? Basically I want to match a file but not match a directory, something like:

```
/foo/bar/baz # does not match
/foo/bar/baz.js # matches
/foo/bar/baz.js/foo # does not match
```

is that possible?

Comment: More reliable way to do it is using `test` on `[^\/]+\.[^\/]+$`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below function

```js
function check(path) {
  return path.split('/').pop().indexOf('.') > -1;
}

console.log(check('/foo/bar/baz.js')); //true
console.log(check('/foo/bar/baz')); //false
console.log(check('/foo/bar/baz.js/foo')); //false
```

Comment: That's not a regular expression.

Comment: Oh sorry missed that out

Answer (score 1):

I though of something like this:

```
/^\/?([^\/]+\/)+[^\/.]+\.[^\/.]+$/g
```

Breakdown:

```
^ start of the string
\/? start with an optional slash
()+ a group that can repeat any amount
    [^\/]+ anything thats not a slash repeated any amount
    \/ a slash
then, the final bit must b
[^\/.]+ any non slash, non dot character, repeat any times
a single dot
[^\/.]+ any non slash, non dot character, repeat any times
$ end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
/\.(\w)*$/g
```

(Warning: not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const isAFileInDirectory = str => /[^\.]\.[^\.\/]+$/.test(str);

console.log(isAFileInDirectory('/foo/bar/baz'));
console.log(isAFileInDirectory('/foo/bar/baz.js'));
console.log(isAFileInDirectory('/foo/bar/baz.js/foo'));
```

Comment: What does the `$` in the end of your regex do?

Comment: It matches the end of the string.

Comment: **end of the string**... did you mean *null character* `\0`?

Comment: No, I most definitely meant `$`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used: `/^[^\.]+\.[^/\.]+$/gi`

```js
console.log(/^[^\.]+\.[^/\.]+$/gi.test('/foo/bar/baz'));
console.log(/^[^\.]+\.[^/\.]+$/gi.test('/foo/bar/baz.js'));
console.log(/^[^\.]+\.[^/\.]+$/gi.test('/foo/bar/baz.js/foo'));
```